# Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. start apache alongside node-red

Tags: software-installation, apache-httpd

I have a problem with apache in (debian 9 64bit). i want to install drupal
[such as this article](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-and-configure-drupal-on-debian-9/) but when i want to start apche showed me this error:

```
mjb@debian:~$ systemctl start apache2
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

and i was installed NODE-RED, before apache.

the NODE-RED use this address : localhost:1880

the apache use port 80.

result of this command **systemctl status apache2.service** :

```
mjb@debian:~$ systemctl status apache2.service
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2018-05-05 15:28:54 +0430; 37min ago
  Process: 1398 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

result of this command **journalctl -xe** :

```
root@debian:/home/mjb# journalctl -xe
May 05 16:09:01 debian CRON[2339]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; 
May 05 16:09:01 debian CRON[2338]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
May 05 16:09:15 debian systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
-- Subject: Unit phpsessionclean.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit phpsessionclean.service has begun starting up.
May 05 16:09:16 debian systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.
-- Subject: Unit phpsessionclean.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit phpsessionclean.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
May 05 16:09:55 debian systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has begun starting up.
May 05 16:09:55 debian apachectl[2399]: apache2: Syntax error on line 225 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 11 of /etc/apache2/sites-
May 05 16:09:55 debian apachectl[2399]: Action 'start' failed.
May 05 16:09:55 debian apachectl[2399]: The Apache error log may have more information.
May 05 16:09:55 debian systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 05 16:09:55 debian systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
May 05 16:09:55 debian systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 05 16:09:55 debian systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

**EDIT:**

in file `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/drupal.conf` i see this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/drupal
ServerName 192.168.15.189
ServerAlias www.example.com
<<Directory "/var/www/html/drupal/">
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/drupal-error_log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/drupal-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

**note** : i use from node-red (localhost:1880/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in the article you have been following, on the line:

> ```
> <<Directory "/var/www/html/drupal/">
> ```

Just remove one of the starting brackets `<`.